# Tap on search Button in android device with appium is not working

Tags: android, appium

I am trying to type in a search box within my app and tap/click on search button (magnifying glass) on keyboard. But I am unable to click/tap on it. I have tried below things: `driver.sendKeyEvent(84);` Appium says it successfully sent in the command but '`search`' does not get tapped. Cursor remains in text box and results do not filter.

```
HashMap swipeObject = new HashMap();swipeObject.put("keycode", 84);((JavascriptExecutor ) driver).executeScript("mobile: keyevent", swipeObject);
```

Appium says: `not yet implemented`

Answer (score 0):

find element by id or path and then use click. 
        driver.findElement(By.id("SearchButton-Id")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath given by UIAutomator")).click();

If you can post the screenshot of UIAutomator, I can tell you xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for search button on keyboard:

```
    driver.sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);
```

For this, you need "import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidKeyCode;"

Answer (score 0):

Try below java code-

driver.executeScript("mobile: performEditorAction", ImmutableMap.of("action", "search"));

action: The name or an integer code of the editor action to be executed. The following action names are supported: normal, unspecified, none, go, search, send, next, done, previous